# Can x11 server run applications without any rendering?

Tags: virtual-machine, graphics-card, xorg

I am trying to use 1 GPU for my main os but switch it to a VM and let that VM use it. But I want the applications on my screen of my main os to stay running. I can do the trick with the gpu switch but I need to shutdown the X11 server for it. Is there a way to say against X11 server to stop using the gpu and do nothing on render calls?

Comment: Most applications that use the GPU tend to be graphical. Are you crypto-mining or something?

Comment: @Burgi i am using it for gaming... I want a windows vm for gaming with only 1 GPU since my CPU doesn't have one builtin. But i want to switch seamless between windows vm and linux. Thats why i want to stop any rendering calls and then switch to VM and game on it and then back to linux for 'not gaming stuff'.